# exchange server 2010 smtp basic authentication

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2010

I have 2 servers. Server 1 is a linux webhosting server. We receive e-mail on that server. Server 2 is Windows where Exchange Server 2010 is running at.

We have a service which runs on the background for getting e-mail. Server with Exchange is running that service and pull each x seconds for new mail.
Now we are moved to a other ISP, the ISP for some reason not supporting SMTP.

We can use our linux server to send the e-mail but requires login by user user@domain.com with password.

I have created in Exchange -> Organisation Configuration -> Hub Transport -> Tab Send Connectors a new connector for the SMTP. This one have a user set for the basic authentication.

However my e-mail stays in the queue and I dont get any feedback from Exchange if something is wrong.

- Normally you create a pop account, set smtp and run. In this case Exchange need to login to make it possible for whole organisation

Do anyone has experience with this?

Kind regards

Comment: Dublicated with that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471861/smtp-authentication-exchange-2010). Do you know what a smarthost is?

Comment: I am aware I posted it on StackOverflow, but the group of people in this community is higher skilled (in my opinion). I am a developer so to answer your question, no I dont know but I think you can tell me more ;-)

Comment: If you have a static IP address then you can just have Exchange send and receive email directly. No need to involve the web server. You would just need to get the new ISP to set a PTR to match. Use Exchange as it was designed - it works better that way.